# Before submitting a paper, should I remove acknowledgement for the sake of anonymity?

Tags: paper-submission, acknowledgement, anonymity

I have this paper to submit. A professor has given great comments on a previous version of my paper. To submit I need to make it anonymous. Should I also remove my acknowledgement. I think that to mention a name in my paper might be regarded as producing a bias in my favor.

Comment: I don't really know these things well, but does the editor have any responsibility for anonymizing papers?

Comment: If you do redact the acknowledgement from the version you submit, I would strongly suggest making this clear in the text (write something like "Acknowledgements: [redacted for anonymity during review process]").  Maybe someone you acknowledge will be a reviewer/referee, and you don't want them to mistakenly think you haven't acknowledged them.

Answer (score 20):

I would remove the acknowledgement. It's better to be on the safe side when you are submitting and do not disclose the data that could be used for author identification. You could always add that part back after review process is over.

If I recall correctly, I have once used a publisher-supplied Latex template that automatically generated pdf file with authors' names and acknowledgement section removed for the sake of anonymity, so the practice of not giving out that kind of information in review copies seems to exist. (EDIT: I remembered well. ACM's sigconf template can be configured for anonymity - in that case acknowledgement section is removed from output pdf file, while in non-anonymous mode this information is retained in the output).